# Alternative method to get data in jQuery than to use parent() and next() repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML Table of Task List Data that I am trying to get all the data values and store them to an object when a row is clicked on.

I have a demo of some HTML and the JavaScript below that is all functioning just as I need it.

The problem is that I know the jQuery part is really bad quality as it calls things like this...

```
$taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().text()
```

I feel these can be improved but I am not sure how so.  Most of this was already done on an existing project that I am trying to clean up and this 1 section is really bugging me.

I would appreciate any help in alternative ways to get the data please?

Or if this is the most efficient way?

Also if I need to I have access to modify some of the HTML if need to add new ID's or data attributes.

**JSFiddle demo**...when you click a link in the Task Title, it will print the values that it selected to the DOM for demo puirposes...: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/2hkz0gp4/5/)

**Demo JavaScript to get Task Data from the DOM Task List and create a JS Object with it:**

```
//Open Task Modal when a Task record is clicked in Task List
$('body').on('click', '.taskName', function() {


    // Set and Cache Task ID from clicked on Task Item
    var taskId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().dataAttr('task-id');

    var $taskEl = $(this);

    // Populate Task Data Object from DOM values
    taskDataObject = {
        //projectId: projectTaskModal.cache.projectId,
        taskId: taskId,
        taskName: $taskEl.text(),
        taskDescription: $taskEl.next('.description').text(),
        taskStatus: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().text(),
        taskPriority: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().text(),
        taskTags: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().text(),
        taskCreatedDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().text(),
        taskModifiedDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().next().text(),
        taskDueDate: $taskEl.parent().parent('td').next().next().next().next().next().next().text(),
    };

});
```

**Demo Task List HTML**

```
<span id="projectIdPlaceholder" data-project-id="1234"></span>

  <table>

  <!-- test task list record 1 -->
  <tr id="task-row-1414135033730" data-task-id="1414135033730">
    <td width="1%" class="task-checkbox">
      <div class="status_update status-checkbox-Not-Started" data-id="1414135033730" data-status="Not Started" id="1414135033730"></div>
    </td>

    <td width="59%" class="task-name">
      <div><span id="1414135033730-taskName" class="taskName strikethrough">Add a Plugin System similar to WordPress Action and Filter Hooks
        <span class="open-description-icon open-description-icon-close" title"toggle="" description="" view"="">+</span>
        </span>
        <div id="1414135033730-taskDescription" class="description" style="display: block;">Project module will Fire Events before and After key events and Plugins in a custom/modulename/plugins/ folder will load and be able to Listen for these Event Hooks and then run it;s own code before and after these actions are executed!</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033730-status" class="Not Started status">                 Not Started</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033730-taskPriority" class="priority">Low</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div class="type">Other</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033730-createdDate" class="createdDate">2014-10-24 07:18:41</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033730-modifiedDate" class="modifiedDate">2014-10-24 07:18:41</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033730-dueDate" class="dueDate">None</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!-- test task list record 2 -->
  <tr id="task-row-1414135033731" data-task-id="1414135033731">
    <td width="1%" class="task-checkbox">
      <div class="status_update status-checkbox-Completed" data-id="1414135033731" data-status="Completed" id="1414135033731"></div>
    </td>

    <td width="59%" class="task-name">
      <div>
        <span id="1414135033731-taskName" class="taskName">Testing Task Record Number 2
        <span class="open-description-icon open-description-icon-close" title"toggle="" description="" view"="">+</span>
        </span>
        <div id="1414135033731-taskDescription" class="description" style="display: block;">My project task description for demo testing task record number 2!</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033731-status" class="Completed status">Completed</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033731-taskPriority" class="priority">High</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div class="type">Magento</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033731-createdDate" class="createdDate">2014-10-27 03:10:14</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033731-modifiedDate" class="modifiedDate">2014-10-27 03:22:24</div>
    </td>
    <td width="10%">
      <div id="1414135033731-dueDate" class="dueDate">06/21/2015</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

Comment: The ID seems pretty consistent can we not break that up pull out the number then do a load of queries on that? so $("#" + selectedId + "-taskName").text() etc

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you'll be able to target elements by class using find: `$taskEl.find('dueDate')` for example.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have Task ID available and the divs all have ID's, I would target the element ID's directly. In jQuery, the more specific you can be, the better.

```
$('body').on('click', '.taskName', function() {

    // Get the task (row) that will be used for running all the selections
    var taskid = $(this).closest("tr").dataAttr('task-id');
    var taskSel = "#" + taskid + "-";

    // Populate Task Data Object from DOM values
    taskDataObject = {

        taskId: taskid;,
        taskName: $(taskSel + "taskName").text(),
        taskDescription: $(taskSel + "taskDescription").text(),
        taskStatus: $(taskSel + "taskStatus").text(),
        taskPriority: $(taskSel + "taskPriority").text(),
        taskTags: $(taskSel + "taskTags").text(),
        taskCreatedDate: $(taskSel + "taskCreatedDate").text(),
        taskModifiedDate: $(taskSel + "taskModifiedDate").text(),
        taskDueDate: $(taskSel + "taskDueDate").text(),
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your different values are in `div` and `span` with a descriptive class name, you could just select them using `find()` and their className within the row that was clicked.

Something like this:

```
//Open Task Modal when a Task record is clicked in Task List
$('body').on('click', '.taskName', function() {

    // Get the task (row) that will be used for running all the selections
    $task = $(this).closest("tr");

    // Populate Task Data Object from DOM values
    taskDataObject = {
        //projectId: projectTaskModal.cache.projectId,
        taskId: $task.data('task-id'),
        taskName: $task.find(".taskName").text(),
        taskDescription: $task.find(".description").text(),
        taskStatus: $task.find(".status").text(),
        taskPriority: $task.find(".priority").text(),
        taskTags: $task.find(".type").text(),
        taskCreatedDate: $task.find(".createdDate").text(),
        taskModifiedDate: $task.find(".modifiedDate").text(),
        taskDueDate: $task.find(".dueDate").text()
    };

});
```

---

Edit: To be consistent, I replaced `$(this).text()` with `$task.find(".taskName").text()`, and `$(this).next(".description").text()` with `$task.find(".description").text()`. And removed `taskId` and `taskEl` as they were redundant.

Edit2: Replaced `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` with `$(this).closest("tr")`. That way if the HTML structure changes in the future (and the number of parents change), still the task row will be selected and the code should work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually selecting each element, I suggest you to use `data-*` attributes to store values and use `JavaScript` to dynamically build the object, for example:

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td data-name="taskName" data-value="Test">
            <div class="foo">Test</div>
        </td>
        <td data-name="taskDate" data-value="1439275213">
            <div class="foo">2014-10-24 07:18:41</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $nodes = $('#table').find('td[data-name]'); // find TDs with 'data-attr'
var attributes = {};
$nodes.each(function() { // generate object with all data-name/data-value pairs
    var $node = $(this);
    attributes[$node.attr('data-name')] = $node.attr('data-value');
});
console.log(attributes); // prints { taskName: "Test", taskDate: "1439275213" }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/uu65ntks/

P. S. This method will also allow you to display values different from their value, for example, to display human-readable date, but to serialize it as unix timestamp.

Comment: In my app, the HTML is built server side, this is just a demo to select the data

Answer (score 0):

There are various options here, depends on what you need,

This example is not the fastest but is closed to best performance,
great usage of this is reloading DOM element from $ selectors, meaning that parallel events processing the DOM will render same thing,
instead of $this = $(this), reelect your dom element, again not the best practice in term of performance (search in dom), still provides the best results over dynamic modified html.

Your call:

```
$('body').on('click', '.taskName', function() {

    var taskId = $(this).attr('id').replace('-taskName', '');
    taskDataObject = {
        //projectId: projectTaskModal.cache.projectId,
        taskId: taskId,
        taskName: $(this).text(),
        taskDescription:$('[id="' + taskId + '-taskDescription"').text(),
        taskStatus:$('[id="' + taskId + '-status"').text(),
        taskPriority: $('[id="' + taskId + '-taskPriority"').text(),
        taskTags: "undefined please defeine corect atribute on div",
        taskCreatedDate: $('[id="' + taskId + '-createdDate"').text(),
        taskModifiedDate: $('[id="' + taskId + '-modifiedDate"').text(),
        taskDueDate: $('[id="' + taskId + '-dueDate"').text(),
    };

        deepTrim(taskDataObject);
        printObjectToDom(taskDataObject);
});
```

you can write custom selector over your main parent html, similar with my example

```
var T_REX = $(this).parent().parent()... whatever;

var T_REX_CUBS = TREX.children();

var taskname = T_REX_CUBS[0].find("div.taskName").text();
```

or the simplest ones

```
var T_REX = $(this).closest('tr');

var taskid = T_REX.attr('data-task-id');

var taskname = T_REX.find("div.taskName").text();
```

Now the fastest option is to save the main parent object, over that apply jquery custom selectors, but this is not the recommend if your data from table is changing real time.